# Random bg color, changing in every refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 9 blocks per page, I wanted to change it's background color randomly, using just same class
(is it possible to use one class?) and it should be different bg color per block.

For instance:

```
block1 = red
block2 = yellow
block3 = green
```

and so on..

I have tried this code: (which is printing same colors at the same time)

```
var colors = ["#99B3FF", "#799979", "#1E1E1E"],
selectedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

header = $(".recent-posts-body");
header.css("background-color", selectedColor);
```

I'm not sure how to implement this using js.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5XUST/ your code works fine

Comment: yes it is. but it's not changing in every block.

Comment: @Yashhy: please don't use code spans (`like this`) for words that aren't keywords in code. For example, `var` or `<html>` should be in a code span, but `this really shouldn't be`. Thank you!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Okay. I thought of highlighting it, thanks will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over each block and assign colours:

```
var colors = ["#99B3FF", "#799979", "#1E1E1E"],
header = $(".recent-posts-body");
$.each( head, function(idx, obj) {
    selectedColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
    obj.css("background-color", selectedColor);
});
```

The above code will not guarantee that every block shall have a different colour from previous block, but the colours are randomly selected from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/5XUST/2/

**CODE**

```
var colors = ["#99B3FF", "#799979", "#1E1E1E", "#AAA", "#FFF", "#CCC"];

var blocks = $(".block");
for(var x = 0; x < blocks.length; x++){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    var selectedColor = colors[random];
    $(blocks[x]).css("background-color", selectedColor ).html(selectedColor);
    colors.splice(random, 1);
}
```

Every time a div gets a background color, this color is removed from the starting so the same color won't appear again. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ["#99B3FF", "#799979", "#1E1E1E"];

$("your elements").each(function()
{
   $(this).css('background-color', colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)]);
});
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eithe/LY2FQ/